# Perl's foreach and changing the looping variable

Tags: perl, foreach

I am writing a script in Perl and have a question about Perl's `foreach` construct.

It appears that if you change one of the loop variables it changes in the actual array.  Is this in fact the case, or have I done something **completely** wrong?

I want to change a string like `abc.abc#a` to `abc_abc_a` (underscores for non alpha-numeric characters),  but I need to preserve the original value in the array for later use.

I have code that looks something like this:

```
@strings = ('abc.abc#a', 'def.g.h#i');
foreach my $str (@strings){
    $str =~ s/[^0-9A-Za-z]/_/g;
    print $str, "\n"; #Actually I use the string to manipulate files.
}
```

I could solve the problem by doing the following:

```
@strings = ('abc.abc#a', 'def.g.h#i');
foreach my $str (@strings){
    my $temp = $str; #copy to a temporary value
    $temp =~ s/[^0-9A-Za-z]/_/g;
    print $temp, "\n"; #$str remains untouched...
}
```

but is there a more efficient way to accomplish this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're not crazy; this is normal behaviour. See [perldoc perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops) under Foreach loops:

> If any element of LIST is an lvalue, you can modify it by modifying VAR inside the 
>   loop.  Conversely, if any element of LIST is NOT an lvalue, any attempt to modify that 
>   element will fail.  In other words, the "foreach" loop index variable is an implicit 
>   alias for each item in the list that you're looping over.

Other loop iterators such as [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) have similar behaviour:

> ```
> map BLOCK LIST  
> map EXPR,LIST
> ```
>
> ...
>   Note that $_ is an alias to the list value, so it can be used to modify the
>   elements of the LIST.  While this is useful and supported, it can
>   cause bizarre results if the elements of LIST are not
>   variables.  Using a regular "foreach" loop for this purpose would be
>    clearer in most cases.
>   See also "grep" for an array composed of those items
>   of the original list for which the BLOCK or EXPR evaluates to true.

You could rewrite your code this way, which would at least save you from adding an extra line:

```
my @strings = ('abc.abc#a', 'def.g.h#i');
foreach my $str (@strings){
    (my $copy = $str) =~ s/[^0-9A-Za-z]/_/g;
    print $copy, "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can always make a copy of the array before modifying elements in it ('`my`' added to appease `strict`), viz.:

```
my @strings = ('abc.abc#a', 'def.g.h#i');
foreach my $str (my @temp = @strings) {
    $str =~ s/[^0-9A-Za-z]/_/g;
    print "$str\n"; #Actually I use the string to manipulate files.
}
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper(\@strings);
```

which returns:

```
abc_abc_a
def_g_h_i
$VAR1 = [
          'abc.abc#a',
          'def.g.h#i'
        ];
```

`@temp` doesn't have scope outside of the `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. As [Programming Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596000271) states, the loop variable is an alias for the current array element and you must save off the loop variable if any modifications are not to affect the original value.

Answer (score 1):

```
my @strings = ('abc.abc#a', 'def.g.h#i');

print join( "\n", ( map { $_ =~ s/[^0-9A-Za-z]/_/gr } @strings ) )."\n";
```

The `r` only works in Perl `5.14` and up.